# Web element is highlighted or grayed out in Katalon Studio?

Tags: katalon-studio

Can someone help with Groovy code in creating a custom keyword in Katalon Studio to check if an element is selected or grayed out?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that opens up Katalon home page and checks whether the "Free Download" button is selected (using WebElement's `.selected` property):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement as WebElement 
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.common.WebUiCommonHelper
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

WebUI.openBrowser("https://www.katalon.com")

def isSelected(TestObject to){
    WebElement element = WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(to, 3)
    return element.selected  
}

TestObject tobject = new TestObject().addProperty("css", ConditionType.EQUALS, ".btn-download")

println(isSelected(tobject))
```